# Hex dump from memory location

Tags: c++, memory-management, pointers, hex, hexdump

I use a pointer to specify some kind of "shared memory" which I use to
exchange data between different processes/threads. Now I would like to have
a hex dump of the content of the shared buffer. Does anyone know how to do that?

thanks,
R

Comment: Are you asking how to write a general purpose hex dump function?

Comment: Roughly speaking, I would say so ;). Basically, I would like to know how I can output the contents at a specific memory location, without knowing that type they are.

Answer (score 15):

Use casts, of course :-) The function should look something 
like this:

```
void Dump( const void * mem, unsigned int n ) {
  const char * p = reinterpret_cast< const char *>( mem );
  for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
     std::cout << hex << int(p[i]) << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Then in use:

```
Foo * f = GetSharedFoo();
Dump( f, somesize );
```

where somesize is how much you want to dump.

Comment: Just looked into my toolbox. Mine also puts a `std::setw(2) << std::setfill( os.widen('0') )` into the stream. But that might be because I write into stream with any character width.

Comment: Yes, setting width & padding is a good idea, but has been discussed here several times before - I was concentrating on the casting of the thing being dumped.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that you probably should cast to `const unsigned char*` to avoid `ff` values to be expanded to `ffffffff` in the subsequent int-cast.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28VS.85%29.aspx). I do not know the Linux equivalent.